# Increase availible memory for python in windows

Tags: python, windows, memory-management

I'm working on a program in python on Windows 7 that matches features between multiple images in real time. It is intended to be the only program running.

When I run it on my laptop, it runs very slowly. However, when I check how much memory it is using with the task manager, it is only using about 46,000 KB. I would like to increase the memory available to the python process so that it can use all available memory.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing image comparisons, chances are good you are CPU-bound, not memory-bound. Unless those are gigantic images, you're probably OK.

So, check your code for performance problems, use heuristics to avoid running unnecessary code, and send what you've got out for code review for others to help you.

Answer (score 4):

Python does not *have* a built-in mechanism for limiting memory consumption; if that's all it's using, then that's all it'll use.

Answer (score 0):

Each process can use the same amount of (virtual) memory that the OS makes available. Python is not special in that regard. Perhaps you'd want to modify your program, but we'd have to see some code to comment on that.